# Regex how to match the string at end of sequence?

Tags: regex

I have a simple string, I want the value at the last - using regex

String Like a `ABC-ABC-ABC-value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following pattern:

```regex
[^-]+$
```

This would match the substring at the very end after the final dash.

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

Use this: `(?:.+-)(.+)$`

First group captures the first part of the string with dash.

The last group captures the text you want

Answer (score 1):

The simplest form would be: `-(\w+)$`. With the desired string in capture group 1.

Explanation:

- `\w`: Capture alphanumeric
- `$`: End of the string

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/IpmM2d/1